# Is it ok to block UI thread while showing an Alert dialog

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I have this method which basically waits for items in the singleton queue to become empty, there is a background service which is running and the service stops once it removes all items in the queue and process each one by one. This code runs in the main thread, what will happen when I call wait here? will the alert dialog still be showing and blocking the user from performing any other action?

```
void waitForService() {
    openConnectionToUploadQueue();
    if(answersQueue.getCount(objInterviewQuestion.getQid()) <= 0){
        answersQueue.close();
        return;
    }
    if(!answersQueue.isInterviewUploadServiceRunning()) {
        answersQueue.startInterviewUploadService();
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.auto_submit_alert_title));
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.uploading_pending_answers);
    AlertDialog waitForServiceDialog = builder.create();
    waitForServiceDialog.show();
    while (answersQueue.getCount(objInterviewQuestion.getQid()) > 0) {
        // do nothing and keep loop running till answersQueue is empty
    }
    waitForServiceDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: That's a bad idea, never block the ui thread, instead have a callback you dismiss the dialog with. Your current implementation may generate anr crashes.

Comment: just realized calling wait() here is stupid edited the question so that I dont appear stupid to future visitors >.>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never block UI Thread. When you hold UI Thread for too long, this is when the system will show a dialog saying `XXX is not responding` and ask user to kill your application.

Instead, you should use a callback style call, and when the service is up, and you receive the method call from callback, you dismiss the dialog.

**Edit:**

As discussed, you would need to implement `BroadcastReceiver`

Here is a demo project of mine for something else, you can use it as a sample on how to create and use `BroadcastReceiver`.

https://github.com/cyfung/ActivityRecognitionSample

Comment: how do I do this my service is built in a manner such that, from my activity I push objects to queue and forget about them, my service takes care of uploading them and there are no callbacks from service. Even if I were to create a callback interface how do I pass the implementation of this interface to the service?

Comment: you just say that you have a service which is responsible for the upload. In your service you should send a `Broadcast` where you Activity should register a `BroadcastReceiver` when the broadcast received for service run finished, you dismiss the dialog

Comment: sadly this doesn't suit me because the service will be called on and off multiple times and most of the time I don't want to show any dialogs

Comment: you should simply keep flag on whether you are waiting to close the dialog. Or even simplier, keep a field of the AlertDialog, if it is not null and you receive the call then you dismiss the Dialog. Even more you can use it as a triggering point and do the same checking `answersQueue.getCount(objInterviewQuestion.getQid()) > 0` before you dismiss the dialog. It is about how you use the tool, not the tool is not working. Wish your coding go smooth.

Comment: ah that makes sense thanks! Can you expand on this point please "Even more you can use it as a triggering point"? @Derek Fung

Comment: Actually it depends on when the `Service` send Broadcast and how `BroadcastReceiver` use the broadcast. For example, if service send Broadcast whenever it finish one task in queue, then if BroadcastReceiver, you should check  `answersQueue.getCount(objInterviewQuestion.getQid())` if it is 0, and your dialog is shown, you call dismiss. If not, just wait for next notification, or even update the dialog showing how many remaining.